# How do I create a cursor (.cur) image file in Photoshop CS4?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, software-recommendation, file-format, cur

I'm using Photoshop CS4 and I need to create a .cur image.  The actual process of doing so is simple enough but I cannot find the necessary Photoshop CS4 plug-in to do so.

Can anybody help me either find the plug-in or show me how to create the .cur file without it?

Answer (score 2):

I dont know how to create this .cur files in photoshop but you can check links below they have useful information for you...

- [There is some discussion about the same](http://www.winmatrix.com/forums/index.php?/topic/4374-help-plugin-for-cur/)
- [Make Cursors using a Professional Authoring Tool](http://www.axialis.com/cursorworkshop/)
- [Create, edit, and apply 1-bit patterns, wallpaper tiles, icons, and
  cursors](http://www.axiomx.com/PixelToolbox/)
- [The Photoshop Plugin Site](http://thepluginsite.com/resources/freeps.htm) so many plugins available here
- [Convert a gif image to .cur image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426372/convert-a-gif-into-a-cur-file)

Hope this will help...

Answer (score -1):

The excellent *ICO (Windows Icon) file format plugin for Photoshop* (http://www.telegraphics.com.au/svn/icoformat/trunk/dist/README.html) allows you to simply Save As a .cur in PhotoShop.